# How do I replace all non-digit characters in a regex except for the period?

Tags: javascript, regular-expressions

In my VF page I have some Javascript to format passed variables.
I have a string eg "Cost is $100.00" from which I need to remove all non-digit characters, EXCEPT the digital period. I want the result to be 100.00

I currently have:

```
var x = "Cost is $100.00";
var y = x.replace(/\D/g, '');
```

which removes all non-digit characters, including the "."
What do I need to do to keep that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write a negated character class with `^` to include the period, `.`, and the set of digits, `0-9`:

```
var z = x.replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '');
```

`z` is then `"100.00"`.

Comment: Seeing a proposed edit prompted me to add this comment. Normally, a period/full-stop is a wildcard (matches any single character), and you'd need to escape it to match a literal "period". However, since it appears in a character class, it does not need to be escaped.